# Can I animate a model made in ZBrush?

Tags: modeling, animation, external-applications, zbrush

I'm new in game modeling and animation, and I really liked how ZBrush works, but blender is better in animation, much easier, but too difficult with modeling.

Can I animate a model made in zBrush?
If yes, how can I do it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can**, here is how:

Export your model from zbrush(id recommend a .obj).in blender you can open the .obj useing (File>Import>Wavefront Obj)

Now your model is ready for animation.

**Note:**
In zbursh it is important that you do not export a raw sculpt, since that will not work for animation in *any* software. Always retopoligize it.

Comment: so i dont need to retopoligize, right?

Comment: sorry, yes i need or yes i don't need?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi, You should always retopoligize a sculpt before anaimation. sorry for being unclear.